# SQL Server Management Studio won't work after Windows Update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssms, windows-update

Came to work this morning, my PC (Win7 x64) had force rebooted by Windows Update. Now, SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008 r2) fails when connecting to a database and trying to expand the tree view, citing:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT:0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

The following updates were installed during the night:

Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2553090)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Web Platform Tools (KB2548139)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Report Viewer (KB2549864)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 TFS Build Explorer (KB2522890)
Security Update for Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (KB2553073)
Security Update for Microsoft Office Groove 2007 (KB2552997)
Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Junk Email Filter (KB2553110)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2570947)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (KB2547352)
Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2553089)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (KB2529927)
Security Update for the 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB2553074)
Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 (KB2583910)
Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2584063)
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2616676)
Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - September 2011 (KB890830)

So, quite a bit. The **Event Viewer shows no errors** (not regarding this, anyway) and all updates were successfully installed. I'm kind of stuck here right now, I've seen some articles recommending re-registering DLLs, but so far that hasn't worked.

Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a fix!

Seems like Internet Explorer is the culprit, for some very strange reason.

- Launch command line in *administrative mode*.
- Go to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer` or `c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer` if you have Win x64.
- Execute `regsvr32 /u ieproxy.dll` (this might throw an error if it isn't loaded)
- Execute `regsvr32 ieproxy.dll`

This did the trick for me (actually, I registered/unregistered one extra time, but that shouldn't have anything to say?)!

Hope this helps anyone!